# Where should I place a "wish" for developers of Ubuntu?

Tags: feature-request

Questions similar to the [In Ubuntu 16.04, how to set shortcut-keys for maximizing a window only horizontally or only vertically?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/940055/in-ubuntu-16-04-how-to-set-shortcut-keys-for-maximizing-a-window-only-horizonta)
lead to a "wish" for developers of Ubuntu.  (After I have got some experience with the Ubuntu 16.04 and tried shaping windows, it appears to me that merely shifting the window title bar to the top or a side of the display, which in the new Ubuntu version maximizes the height or width of the window, is not sufficient.) Where should I place such a "wish"?

Comment: This is about the process of developing Ubuntu rather than *the Ask Ubuntu site itself*, so it should really be on the main site. That is, this is an attempt to ask how to file a feature request for Ubuntu, not an attempt to file one for Ask Ubuntu. So let's close this and migrate it to the main site. (It will then likely be made a duplicate of [the question muru linked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28440/where-can-i-send-feature-requests). @TomášPečený If that *doesn't* tell you what you need to know, you can **[edit]** your question to explain that. Either way this belongs on main.)

Comment: @EliahKagan Considering this would be a duplicate of [the post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28440/where-can-i-send-feature-requests) muru links I don't think it is worth migrating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called a "feature request": [Where can I send feature requests?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28440/where-can-i-send-feature-requests)

Note that Ubuntu is moving to GNOME Shell, so feature requests for Unity won't be of much priority. And they probably won't be backported to 16.04.